# How to create a YTD comparison of This and Last year sales?

Tags: reporting, opportunity

I need to compare YTD sales of this and last year sales.

How can I achieve that with a simple formula field on the opportunity object?

YTD = Year - To - Date - e.g.: all sales until this date. (and in last year: same date in last year)

- I don't mind the "Transactional" feature of SF. A real time values/data is fine.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with formula field. The reason i say this because in formula you can not refer other records of same object. Due to this you will not know YTD sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done is:

create a formula number field

Name: YTD index

Value:

```
case(YEAR(CloseDate), 
YEAR(Today()),1, 
YEAR(Today())-1,IF(CloseDate <= date(year(Today())-1,month(Today()),day(Today())),1 , null), 
Null 
)
```

What it does : for current year sales: set YTD index = 1.
For last year, if the close date is less than : today in last year: set YTD = 1.

This gives me an immediate, real time, YTD comparison of sales for both years.

On the requested reports, I add the filter of: YTDindex = 1. Won = true. and this and last year.
Merge dates by year/month as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce is a transactional database, using real-time values. To report on historical data, you would need **analytic snapshots**. More info can be found here:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm

Comment: I need this in real time data. Not only on the snapshots.